# A word for "one who tames wild animals"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, agent-nouns

I want to know a single word that conveys this meaning "one who tames wild animals".

Comment: Can you show that you did seriously try to find an answer first? (That's almost a prerequisite on ELU.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Tamer*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/tamer).

As simple as that.

If they were not wild animals, they would not need to be *tamed* in the first place, perhaps. As such, a *tamer* tames (trains) only wild animals (and not domesticated ones).

For others, we have *trainer*.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the expression:

> *to [break](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/break?s=t) an animal*,

typically used with horses. As in,

> I break horses.

By extension, you could refer to this person as a *breaker* of horses.

Comment: Horse a wild animal? Sure?

Comment: "domesticated in Egypt and Asia at a very early period ... the wild species from which it was derived is not certainly known. The feral horses of America are domestic horses that have run wild; and it is probably true that most of those of Asia have a similar origin." [Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48]

Comment: Try explaining that to a bucking colt. :/